# Regex match string UNTIL string in a comma separated line

Tags: regex

All words start with "Passed", but I only want to match those that also end with "Unique".

```
Input:
PassedShownWeekUnique,PassedShownDayUnique,PassedFailedWeek,PassedFailedDayUnique,Passed1Week,Passed1WeekUnique

Desired output:
PassedShownWeekUnique,PassedShownDayUnique,PassedFailedDayUnique,Passed1WeekUnique
```

I tried regex `Passed.*` and it matches everything. `Passed.*Unique` isn't working, anyone help?

Comment: Which language are you using?

Comment: Your regex is greedy, meaning it's matching as much as possible before matching Unique. Make it ungreedy by using a `?` -- `Passed.+?Unique`

Comment: Have you tried grep Unique$ filename.txt

Answer (score 2):

Just use the following. Match from Passed, then everything, until Unique

```
Passed.*Unique

if [[ $line =~ Passed.*Unique ]]; then echo line matched $line done; fi
```

EDIT: Since op revised his question to be a comma separated line.

```
line=PassedShownWeekUnique,PassedShownDayUnique,PassedFailedWeek,PassedFailedDayUnique,Passed1Week,Passed1WeekUnique
REGEX=Passed.*Unique
IFS=','; 
for word in $line; do 
    if [[ $word =~ $REGEX ]]; then 
        echo matched $word
    fi
done
```

Output:

```
matched PassedShownWeekUnique
matched PassedShownDayUnique
matched PassedFailedDayUnique
matched Passed1WeekUnique
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either use the regex:

```
Unique$
```

to get lines that end with the word "Unique", or:

```
^Passed.+?Unique$
```

to get lines that start with "Passed" and end with "Unique". Depending on your specific implementation, you may want to choose one or the other.

---

And if you have comma-separated input, as you described:

```
(Passed.+?Unique),|$
```

This will capture each instance of a word that starts with "Passed" and ends with "Unique". You can check each capture group to print out the item that it matched.

Comment: I realized my input is actually comma separated: PassedShownWeekUnique,PassedShownDayUnique,PassedFailedWeek,PassedFailedDayUnique,Passed1Week,Passed1WeekUnique

how would I match these? :(

Comment: Perhaps you should edit your question, then - that is a significant detail that you got wrong.

Comment: agreed, in that case you want to split the entire line before matching

Comment: Edited my question for comma-separated support using capture groups.

Comment: the edited answer still matches everything in the input.  The entire input line starts with "Passed" and ends with "Unique", though it's separated by commas in the middle, this answer still matches the entire line.

Comment: Honestly, you can't really only do this with Regex, you need some sort of language support. The ideal thing to do here would be to split on `,` and check if each string starts with "Passed" and ends with "Unique".

Answer (score 0):

How about you try to use `^` and `$`

```
^   Matches the empty string at the beginning of a line; also represents the characters not in the range of a list.

$   Matches the empty string at the end of a line.
```

So something like this

`^Passed.*?Unique$`

You can read more about it [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_04_01.html).

Comment: Unfortunately he edited his post, the items are comma-separated, this is no longer correct.

Comment: Cool, looks like you answered it.

Comment: this matches the entire input string since it's one line, and doesn't filter out words without Unique

Comment: Yes, because you changed the question midway :)